# Network is unreachable after move

Tags: networking, server

I've got a server at home, and I've just moved. I never had problems at the old address connecting it to the internet, but at the new address, the server is refusing to connect.

I've verified so far that all cables work, and the setup gets me connection on other devices.

`ip a` says this about the network port:

```
eno1: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether B4:7a:f1:dd:a0:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::b67a:f1ff:fedd:a05a/64 scope link
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Ping to other members of the network fails. Router does not seem to recognize the server as connected either. Any and all ideas and questions for more information welcome

More information:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Server

Network configuration went entirely automatic last time around. It's a server, so I'm doing everything by command line. Server is intended to be assigned a static IP for hosting several game worlds (Minecraft among others), though that is assigned in the router.

I have the same ISP though they did send me a new router.

Comment: You need to provide more information in order to get help. What OS are you using? What version? Desktop or server? How is your network device configured? Static IP or DHCP? How did you set it up...from command line or a GUI? Please provide more detail. Specifically contents of your config files and screen shots.

Comment: @mpboden what config files would you like information from? Also, would it be likely to be faster/easier to extract my data and fresh reinstall?

Comment: Update question with output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Are you using the same or a different router? Since you've indicated that you're providing a static IP from your router, have you tried renewing the DHCP lease on the server? Have you looked into the router logs to see if there's a problem with the static mapping?

Comment: Is this a new router? What settings did you change in the router after the move? Are you using the same ISP? Is the router provided by the ISP? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506619/edit) and add all these information.